# door not sitting flush with weatherstripping

Tags: doors, door-frame

I've got an exterior door that isn't tight to the weather stripping on the latch side.

The door is level and plumb.

The door has a deadbolt and separate knob lock.

If I bring the knob strike plate closer to the middle of the jamb I can get the door to sit more flush with the weather stripping but there is still a gap. Further, by doing this, the latch is at the edge of strike plate and kind of sticks when opening/closing.

I've read elsewhere that this could be due to the frame being warped. Is there anything I can do without re-framing the door?

Comment: is the gap between the door and the weatherstripping parallel for the whole length of the door? Perhaps it needs repositioning.

Comment: more or less, yes

Comment: do you thing the hinges need to come in?

Comment: reposition the weatherstripping. The door should meet the frame properly anyway.

Comment: how so? it sits in a premade channel

Comment: How am I expected to know that? Some weatherstripping is fitted afterwards... If you don't explain well then it is difficult to answer...

Comment: sorry, i thought that was common practice. just seen it that way in every house i've had to deal with it in.

Comment: Common practice in your location may not be common somewhere else...